# php Выполнение параметризованной функции на сервере ms sql

Tags: php, sql-server

доброе время суток, коллеги!

мне нужно получить результат выполнения функции на сервере ms sql для сайта работаю через php

```
<?php
$serverName = "127.0.0.1\sqlexpress";

/* Get UID and PWD from application-specific files.  */
$uid = file_get_contents("C:\Files\uid.txt");
$pwd = file_get_contents("C:\Files\pwd.txt");
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,
                     "PWD"=>$pwd,
                     "Database"=>"FPatology");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
     echo "Unable to connect.</br>";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


$tsql="select * from dbo.fn_select_PHPServerA()";  --функция на сервере без параметров!

if ($res = sqlsrv_query($conn,$tsql)) 
{

} 
else
{ 
    echo "Statement could not be prepared.\n";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

echo "<table align=center, border=1>\n";

echo "\t<tr>\n \t\t<th> Поле1 </th>\n \t\t<th> Поле2 \t\t</th>\n 
                   \t\t<th> Поле3</th>\n  \t\t<th> Поле4</th>\n 
                   \t\t<th>   Поле5  </th>\n  \t\t<th> Поле6</th>\n  
                   \t\t<th>   Поле7  </th>\n  \t\t<th> Поле8 </th>\n  \t\t<th> Поле9  </th>\n 
                   \t\t<th> Поле10 </th>\n  \t\t<th> Поле11 </th>\n  \t\t<th> Поле12 </th>\n 
                   \t\t<th> Поле13</th>\n   \t\t<th> Поле14 </th>\n  \t\t<th> Поле15 </th>\n \t</tr>\n";
for ($i=0; $row = sqlsrv_fetch($res); $i++) 
{ 
    echo "\t<tr> \n";
    echo "\t\t<td> ".sqlsrv_get_field( $res, 0 )."</td>\n";     
    echo "\t\t<td> ".sqlsrv_get_field( $res, 1 )."\t\t</td>\n";
    echo "\t\t<td> ".sqlsrv_get_field( $res, 2 )."\t\t</td>\n";
    echo "\t\t<td> ".sqlsrv_get_field( $res, 3 )."\t\t</td>\n";
    echo "\t\t<td> ".sqlsrv_get_field( $res, 4 )."\t\t</td>\n";
    echo "\t\t<td> ".sqlsrv_get_field( $res, 5 )."\t\t</td>\n";
    echo "\t\t<td> ".sqlsrv_get_field( $res, 6 )."\t\t</td>\n";
    echo "\t\t<td> ".sqlsrv_get_field( $res, 7 )."\t\t</td>\n";
    echo "\t\t<td> ".sqlsrv_get_field( $res, 8 )."\t\t</td>\n";
    echo "\t\t<td> ".sqlsrv_get_field( $res, 9 )."\t\t</td>\n";
    echo "\t\t<td> ".sqlsrv_get_field( $res, 10 )."\t\t</td>\n";
    echo "\t\t<td> ".sqlsrv_get_field( $res, 11 )."\t\t</td>\n";
    echo "\t\t<td> ".sqlsrv_get_field( $res, 12 )."\t\t</td>\n";
    echo "\t\t<td> ".sqlsrv_get_field( $res, 13 )."\t\t</td>\n";
    echo "\t\t<td> ".sqlsrv_get_field( $res, 14 )."\t\t</td>\n";
    echo "\t</tr>\n";

} 
echo "</table>\n";

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $res);

sqlsrv_close( $conn);


?>
```

все работает отлично, я получаю таблицу с данными.
но, как только я пытаюсь выполнить на сервере функцию с передаваемыми параметрами и пишу

```
    $tsql="select * from dbo.fn_select_PHPServerB(@ndoc)";  --функция на сервере с параметрами!
```

добавляя собственно параметры

```
 $ndoc="7";
 $params=array($ndoc);

if ($res = sqlsrv_query($conn,$tsql,$params))
```

мне при открытии сайта выдает

> `## Statement could not be prepared. ##`

и далее крокозяблики

вопрос: как мне отдать команду на выполнение функции с параметрами
заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

создаем переменную, задаем ее значение и присваиваем

```
    $ndoc="7";

    $params=array($ndoc);
    $tsql="select * from dbo.fn_select_PHPServerB('".$ndoc."')";
```

далее, без изменений

```
    if ($res = sqlsrv_query($conn,$tsql,$params)) 
    {}
```